# Display a Shuffle of button text and backgrounds

Tags: java, android, button, random, background

I have a button in xml. On button press I wish to rapidly change the background and Text on that button.

I normally would use a code like this for the final result:

```
String rndm[]  = {"A","B","C","D"};
{rnd = rndm[(int) (Math.random() * rndm.length)];}

{Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setText(String.valueOf(rnd));
btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));}
```

Before that is called though I would like perhaps a second or two of a "shuffling" effect.

I have tried using java.util.timer like this:

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                           

                    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
                        new java.util.TimerTask() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

String rndm[]  = {"A","B","C","D"};
    {rnd = rndm[(int) (Math.random() * rndm.length)];}

{Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setText(String.valueOf(rnd));
btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));}

}}}, 100 );
```

Then making a few of these with different backgrounds to fire one after the other. I just can't seem to get the hang of it.

I may need a whole new method to do what I want to do, but I am not sure what the best wat to accomplish what I need is.

Comment: `EventQueue` is part of awt which is not a part of Android SDK ... You had used `runOnUiThread` with empty Runnable implementation...

Comment: Well that would be why I was so confused when I read about using it then :)

Comment: I've edited it to keep the trolls at bay. So, do you happen to know how to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and make sure that the code that you want to run is in the runnable method :-)

Try something like this from your Activity

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
....

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        // set your button color here, no need to use runOnUiThread()
        // as this run() method is executed on Main thread
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this now. :)

Comment: Sorry it took so long, theres about 1000 lines of code in the activity lol and one I added this snippet I was throwing an error... which led to an error... which led to an error... an then... IT WORKED! Thank you so much, this actually solved two of my issues, one in a different activity.